# pass JOIN results to a record and erases duplicates

Tags: postgresql, join, distinct, plpgsql

I use PostgreSQL 10. This is the structure of two tables

```
nike
id - name - editor_id

adidas
id - name - editor_id
```

What I want to do is to select all the nikes and adidas according to a specific `editor_id`. The result set has to be in the form :

`id(nike or adidas) - name(nike or adidas) - editor_id - isNike`

`isNike` is a boolean, so if true is nike, if false is adidas.

So, select all where `editor_id`, put them in that specific form, add that boolean flag, avoid doubles and return.

I created a pl/pgsql PostgreSQL function

```
CREATE  FUNCTION myfunction(id bigint)
RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, name text, editor_id bigint, isNike boolean) 
AS $$
DECLARE
query text;
firstrecord record;
BEGIN    

    query := '
    SELECT
    nike.name, nike.id, nike.editor_id,
    adidas.name, adidas.id, adidas.editor_id
    FROM
    adidas left join nike
    ON nike.editor_id = adidas.editor_id
    WHERE
    nike.editor_id ';

        FOR myrecord IN 
        EXECUTE format(query)  USING id
         LOOP
           IF myrecord.adidas.id IS NOT NULL THEN
             RETURN QUERY VALUES(myrecord.adidas.id, myrecord.adidas.name, myrecord.adidas.editor_id, false);  
           END IF;
           IF myrecord.pid IS NOT NULL THEN
              RETURN QUERY VALUES(myrecord.nike.id, myrecord.nike.name, myrecord.nike.editor_id, true);  
           END IF;
        END LOOP; 


    RETURN; 
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This works, but I get doubles in my resuts. I tried various combinations of `select distinct` and `left join`, `inner join` or `cross join` but I still get doubles, like :

```
id - name - editor_id - isNike
1 - aaa - 3 - true
43 - bbb - 9 - false
5 - ccc - 58 - true
1 - aaa - 3 - true --double
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you want to use [UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-union.html) feature.

In question, you say that you want to pull for specific editor_id, but in result set, there are different editor_ids. I am going to assume that you want to pull results for specific editor_id(if that is not the case, just remove where clause from example bellow). Also, you are using stored procedure, but you can easily put next query in sp if necessary:

```sql
SELECT id, name, editor_id, true as is_nike 
FROM nike
WHERE editor_id = 3
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, editor_id, false as is_nike 
FROM adidas
WHERE editor_id = 3
```

NOTICE: I name is_nike instead of isNike just to follow some PostgreSQL naming conventions (lower_case_with_underscores(snake cased) for names(identifiers))